# Why were D/CAS tapes unusable for audio?

Tags: recording

D/CAS a.k.a digital cassette was a data storage medium used in streamers. It looked like an audio compact cassette (and was mechanically compatible with tape recorders), but putting a D/CAS cassette into a tape recorder and trying to record some music resulted in silence during playback.

Given that those D/CAS cassettes had a magnetic tape inside, how come audio recording was totally impossible? I could imagine the audio being muffled / distorted / quiet due to bias / magnetic field strength mismatch, but no signal at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These cassettes are physically different than your music cassette: The magnetic hysteresis curve of the material was optimized for being magnetized one or the other way, maximally. This is owed to the advantages that has for storing binary data

[image: Signal illustration from Teac MT-2ST/20D-10 Maintenance manual]<sup>Source: [Teac MT-2ST/20D-10 Maintenance manual](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_teacMT2ST10D10StreamingCassetteTapeMaintenance_12078754/page/n25/mode/1up)</sup>

Audio cassettes on the other hand are optimized for allowing storage of a value-continuous signal. So, imagine a smooth line in the figure above where you see the rather square "Magnetized Condition on Tape".

So, a write head for audio did very little to the magnetization of a streamer tape. Basically, you're not writing "strong" enough.

To complicate matters, a D/CAS system is designed to work with adaptive gain control (AGC), meaning that it's not as paramount that a tape holds absolute levels well – so that the analog fidelity that an analog playback system would require is not a design goal of the tape composition. On the contrary – it's desirable that weak modifications of the writer's magnetic field strength have little influence on the magnetization of the tape. Thus, writing nice benign-amplitude analog signal to a D/CAS tape is bound to have ideally no measurable effect.

In reality, the digital tape is used at around 320 bit/mm (and in four diagonally striping tracks), meaning that music cassette recorders, which run at 47.6 mm/s and record audio  bandwidth of ca 9.4 kHz (that's a conveniently chosen number by me) would operate at around 1/2 of the bandwidth, but *length-wise across* the diagonal stripes – probably ending up demagnetizing them a bit, and otherwise being at best weakly modulating the much-stronger, much-higher frequency content, which would lead to the played back sound mostly getting absorbed by low-pass filtering otherwise used to suppress tape hissing.

Comment: What physical form does this optimization take?

Comment: @user253751 as said, probably a different formulation of the magnetic tape, and definitely different mechanical properties of the tape, as they are supposed to run much faster. I only have block diagrams/schematics from the maintenance manual, but it would suggest this is a higher-coercivity tape than your typical audio tapes (and these already differ – I remember the "Type" switch on the older recorders in my childhood!); I'd expect them to be closer to type II than to type IV (based on economic reasoning), but generally high-coercivity media.